# Q : Rental Car Calculator | Use a sentinel value loop

Tags: java, if-statement, static, double, summary

I am confused on if I am following this right and was kind of looking for reassurance along with some help. So my main question is am I following my instructor question is: when he says build it using a sentinel value loop?

Secondly, how can I round the Total to only two decimals?

if it helps my assignment is this:

Instructions: Use a sentinel value loop.

Ask each user for:

Type of vehicle (May use something other than strings, such as: 1 for economy, 2 for sedan, etc.)
Days rented
Calculate the (For each customer):

Rental cost,
Taxes,
Total Due.
There are three different rental options with separate rates: Economy @ 31.76, sedan @ 40.32, SUV @ 47.56. [Note: only whole day units to be considered (no hourly rates)].

Sales tax is = to 6% on the TOTAL.

Create summary data with:

Number of customers
Total money collected.
Also, Include IPO, algorithm, and desk check values (design documents).

{MY DESIGN & PROGRESS}

package yipe;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Umm {

```
int count = 0;
static int days;
static double DailyFee, NontaxTotal, CarType, Total;



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What vehical would you like to rent?\n");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for an economy car\n");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for a sedan car\n");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for an SUV");
    CarType = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (CarType == 1)
          DailyFee=31.76;
        else if(CarType == 2)
          DailyFee=40.32;
        else if(CarType == 3)
          DailyFee=43.50;

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of days rented. (Example; 3) : ");
    days = keyboard.nextInt();

    NontaxTotal = (DailyFee * days);
    Total = (NontaxTotal * 1.06);







    System.out.printf("The total amount due is $" + Total);

}
```

}

Comment: It appears your instructor wants you to create a loop and have multiple customers rent cars

Comment: *"Use a sentinel value **loop**"* I don't see any loops in your code.

Comment: @Andreas how would i look into creating a loop, I feel so lost and I'm sorry :(.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brandon, There is no sentinel loop. In my point of view, this is the program that you want,

```
import java.util.*;

public class Stack3{
public static void main(String []args){
    int count=0;
    int days;
    double DailyFee=0, NontaxTotal, CarType, Total,FullTotal=0;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("If there are any customer press 1 else press 0");
    int cus=in.nextInt();
    // this is sentinel loop
    while(cus!=0){
        count++;
        System.out.print("What vehical would you like to rent?\n");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for an economy car\n");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for a sedan car\n");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 for an SUV");
        CarType = in.nextInt();
        if (CarType == 1)
              DailyFee=31.76;
        else if(CarType == 2)
              DailyFee=40.32;
        else if(CarType == 3)
              DailyFee=43.50;

        System.out.print("Please enter the number of days rented. (Example; 3) : ");
        days = in.nextInt();
        double x=days;
        NontaxTotal = (DailyFee * x);
        Total = (NontaxTotal * 1.06);
        FullTotal+=Total;
        //included 2 decimals only
        System.out.printf("The total amount due is $ %.2f \n",Total);

        System.out.println("If there are any customer press 1 else press 0");
        cus=in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Count of customers :- "+count);
    System.out.printf("Total of the Day :- %.2f",FullTotal);
}
}
```

Comment: I had been playing around in eclipse java since I asked this, I came up with something similar to this but not as clean. Thank you a lot! Referencing this you answered a lot of questions. Also, I wish I could like this up or anything to give back my gratitude. Thank you, A Lot! :)

Comment: Anyway, I'm happy to hear that.